# how can setup monitoring system in data pipeline in Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, pipeline

Data inputs to the pipeline comes from database or web logger. Pipeline processes it and puts into HDFS and moves data to NoSQL database. Monitoring system will be monitoring this end to end.

Answer (score 0):

You can think  of using ELK stack( ElasticSearch, Logstash, Kibana). On each node, ingestion, processing and insert into db, please see if you can add logs about each file/record your are going to process.

You can deploy logstash on each node and write parsing logic for the same, write those to ElasticSearch and visualize those using Kibana.

You can also think about using Watcher plugin from Elastic.co to generate alerts in case of errors.

Following are some links for you to get started.

[Install EKL](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/install-elasticsearch-kibana-logstash-on-windows.html)

[Log Analysis](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/log-analytics-using-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana.html)

[Alerting](http://hadooptutorials.co.in/tutorials/elasticsearch/real-time-alerting-using-elasticsearch-watcher.html)